# Unable to get Access token in Canvas LMS

Tags: bitnami, canvas-lms

I am unable to get the access token when I post a request using Postman. I am receiving the authorization code from the browser and passing the authorization in the Postman request. I have attached screenshot and I am receiving HTTP status as 400 Bad Request with a message

{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "authorization_code not found"
}

Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong here?

[image]